# Upgrade Windows installation from command line [DISM/ImageX]

Tags: windows, windows-10, dism, imagex

One of the most amazing things I learnt on this site is how to install Windows without using the setup, from the [command line](https://superuser.com/questions/490476/how-can-i-install-windows-8-on-my-hdd-without-the-use-of-a-usb-or-dvd).

Now I want to upgrade an Windows 10 build 10240 installation (on an offline partition) to Windows 10 version 1511, build 10586* from the command line using `dism` or `imagex`.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

`DISM /Apply-Image /ImageFile:E:\sources\install.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:F:\` fails with `Access is denied.`

`DISM /Online /Get-TargetEditions` outputs `Education` and `Enterprise` which means you can only upgrade it those two editions.

If not on an offline partition, can it be done on the online/running Windows partition?

---

*I downloaded the ISO from MSDN `en_windows_10_multiple_editions_version_1511_x64_dvd_7223712.iso`

Comment: Hopefully you opened an elevated command prompt.

Comment: @GaneshR. DISM doesn't run without elevation. That access denied is due to not being able to change ACLs on the existing files.

Comment: `Elevated permissions are required to run DISM.
Use an elevated command prompt to complete these tasks.`

Comment: I doubt that DISM can be used to do upgrades. The setup also starts other tools to migrate user data/settings. Why do you want to do it with DISM?

Comment: If you just want to upgrade your Windows installation, why dont you mount the ISO file -> run it and do an in place upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I know nobody at SuperUser like to hear **It's Impossible™** but unfortunately, it looks like that is the case with Windows (at the moment anyway).

Windows, unlike Linux doesn't have the provision to [update files as they're being used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196897/1768141). On Linux systems, you can install an update for a program is currently in use and unlike Windows, Linux doesn't require process termination in order to finish the update.

Linux systems will let you continue using the older version of the program until you close it of your own volition. The next time you start the program, it will have updated to the new version. Linux achieves this kind of 'in-place file modifications' like this:

> When you open a file, the kernel follows the link, and assigns the
>   inode a file descriptor (a number that it keeps track of internally).
>   When you delete the file, you are "unlinking" the inode; the file
>   descriptor still points to it.
>   You can create a new file with the
>   exact same name as the old file after deleting it, effectively
>   "replacing" it, but it will point to a different inode. Any programs
>   that still have the old file open can still access the old file via
>   the file descriptor, but you have effectively upgraded the program in
>   place.
>   As soon as the program terminates (or closes the file), and
>   starts up (or tries to access it again), it accesses the new file, and
>   there you have it, a completely in-place replacement of a file!
>   **<sub>Source: [toolbox.com](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/locutus/why-linux-can-be-updated-without-rebooting-12826)</sub>**

This opens Linux to the [possibility of installing system upgrades without having to reboot the machine](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/60630/are-restart-after-updates-really-necessary/), and not surprisingly [Linux and UNIX users brag about how they haven't restarted their systems since George Bush Sr. was president](http://www.tested.com/tech/pcs/1141-how-often-do-you-really-need-to-reboot-your-pc/).

However, it may not be that simple ([even for *nix users](https://askubuntu.com/q/29268/274291)) and the UNIX/Linux systems that make do without rebooting for years [aren't your regular desktop computers](https://superuser.com/a/498184/167187). Tools like [Ksplice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ksplice) and [live-patching support](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.0#head-9aa7c8499b42911a48c02b24f367bf2bc6db8606) introduced in [Linux kernel 4](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/linux-kernel-4-0-new-features) definitely make it easier though.

It seems like Windows has tried to reduce unnecessary reboots over time and the newest versions can [upgrade many types of drivers without the need for rebooting](http://www.howtogeek.com/182817/htg-explains-why-does-windows-want-to-reboot-so-often/) but it's just [not as flexible as Linux](https://superuser.com/q/808468/167187) [in this type of situations](https://askubuntu.com/a/197727/274291).

As for upgrading an offline Windows installation, I couldn't find much on that.

Answer (score -1):

DISM/ ImageX is designed for working with Installable & Installed Windows Images as a whole.

But, it does not have any functionality to add updates to existing images.

**Answer**: It can not be done with DISM/ ImageX.

**Note:** As additional information I can suggest the following:

For that you need to get on the MDL forums and look at some threads:

1. To use a tool to download updates and then
2. Follow some update Slipstream-ing guides

   - http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/10872-Windows-Updates-Downloader-Project
   - https://techjourney.net/windows-updates-downloader-wud-224-build-875-for-download-with-no-wga-validation/
   - http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/64939-Windows-Update-MiniTool

There are many such tools on MDL, so I am not sure which one would fit best and work for your scenario as I have not updated to Win 10 and have used them on Win 7/8 only for slipstreaming updates & Service Packs.

A word of caution, as these were for Windows 7 & 8 where updates were pulled by clients from MS Servers, I am not sure how/ if they or their updated replacements can do the same for Windows 10, given how MS now pushes and controls updates differently.

Hopefully you can still download updates you want and choose.

Additional Alternatives:

http://www.winbuzzer.com/2015/08/02/slipstreaming-windows-10-how-to-create-up-to-date-windows-10-iso-files-with-all-available-hotfixes-patches-and-security-updates-xcxwbt/

www.ntlite.com

Comment: I don't want to update ISOs, I want to update an existing Windows 10 installation on another partition.